# Docker COPY command does not copy

Tags: postgresql, docker, copy

I've read several same questions, but it still unclear to me why COPY command doesn't work properly. Here is my example:
`a.txt` placed near `Dockerfile` which contains the following code

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile

FROM postgres:11

WORKDIR /usr/lib/postgresql/11/lib
COPY a.txt .
```

that I ran `docker build .` and get the output

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.584kB
Step 1/3 : FROM postgres:11
11: Pulling from library/postgres
aed007321795: Pull complete 
702c74af4354: Pull complete 
ef123e2ab09b: Pull complete 
c84418d8530c: Pull complete 
b579800618be: Pull complete 
6562ab9a134a: Pull complete 
1c9daa412a3b: Pull complete 
ef585939c140: Pull complete 
441afbb7b4bb: Pull complete 
c7aa402b2495: Pull complete 
3890ec9ba5d6: Pull complete 
6a4fce211dfc: Pull complete 
380c4b145ef6: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:944f2e7c91c48e41153e5a20a27baaf251da425931e7e5e43dc46c5a961ddfe0
Status: Downloaded newer image for postgres:11
 ---> c136798ef3a3
Step 2/3 : WORKDIR /usr/lib/postgresql/11/lib
 ---> Running in 800e2be9eb49
Removing intermediate container 800e2be9eb49
 ---> 120f56733739
Step 3/3 : COPY a.txt a.txt
 ---> ea1fd6600166
Successfully built ea1fd6600166
```

To start container I use `docker run -it -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -p 5430:5432/tcp postgres:11`. After attaching to the container `a.txt` doesn't appear in the mentioned directory.

Comment: You're not running your built image (which doesn't have a tag, just the image ID `ea1f...`), you're running the unmodified `postgres:11` image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David Maze mentioned, you're not running your own image. You're running the original `postgres:11` image.

First of all you should build your image like this:

```
docker build -t NEW_NAME:TAG_VERSION .
```

Now you can run this to see and confirm:

```
docker run -it -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -p 5430:5432/tcp NEW_NAME:TAG_VERSION
```